# How to call a user provided variable in Cloud Foundry to a SpringBoot App

Tags: spring-boot, sap-cloud-foundry

I have created a Spring app and deployed it to the cloud foundry. I have set some user-defined variables into it using the cf set_env command. How can I call my user-defined variable into my Spring app?
The variable before being set as an environment variable was defined as String url= "https://78d090ba-8791-46b6-93b7-fc0bc78d5d7c.mock.pstmn.io/stuff".
In cloud foundry, I set the key as topics and the value as this url. How can I call this to my Spring app?